# event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") works for paste event, not for copy event in firefox

Tags: javascript, events, clipboarddata

Currently I am learning javascript as a beginner and following the book "Professional Javascript for Web Developers" by Nicholas Zakas. There I came across clipboard events and tried to implement few scripts from the book.

What I observed is event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") can retrieve the text for paste event but not for copy event.

> > > To explain more I put an alert for copy event:
> > >         alert(event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain"))

When I tried to copy the corresponding field's value a blank alert pop up is shown,above code is not being able to retrieve the copied value.

> > > Next I have put the same alert for the paste event. Now when I copied and pasted some text in the corresponding field the alert pop up is able to show the copy pasted value properly.

My question is : Is this desired behavior? Am I missing something ? Can anybody please explain this behavior ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RaymondChen , I am aware of selection object/event. Here I want to know whether the copied text(not selected) is retrievable through the clipboarddata object or not. And if not then what is the reason behind that ?

Comment: This is spelled out in [the specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html#event-types-and-details). The text is copied to the clipboard if you leave the event unhandled. You get the event first so you can override the default.